# Learning About the Poisson Kernel

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Does anyone know any good resources on the the Poisson kernel? I'm really looking for a measure theoretic approach to harmonic boundary problems. If anyone knows any such books, that would be much appreciated.